# Count the area of the triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, the task is to write the code that will count the area of the triangle on the mathematical plane. However not just it, but use in the code the function, that will count the distance between 2 points on the plane.
So, what we have: 6 points like (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) and we need to write code for the area of the triangle using a function that counts the distance between 2 points on the plane.
P.S: one point = (x1, y1)

What is the problem? IDK
Let's see my code:

```
def length(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    z = (abs(x1 - x2) ** 2 + abs(y1 - y2) ** 2) ** (1/2)
    return z

a, b, c, d, e, f = float(input()), float(input()), float(input()), float(input()), float(input()), float(input())

a = length(a, b, c, d)
b = length(a, b, e, f)
c = length(c, d, e, f)
p = a + b + c
ans = (p(p - a)(p - b)(p - c)) ** (1/2)
print(ans)
```

Unfortunately, I receive a mistake: "'float' object is not callable"
PLZ, help with this code and maybe u will help with input. It is actually strange 6 input() in a row.

Comment: `ans = (p(p - a)(p - b)(p - c)) ** (1/2)`  It thinks you are trying to call p  change it to `ans = (p * (p - a)(p - b)(p - c)) ** (1/2)`

Comment: ohhh. Sorry, yeap. So stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `p(p-a)` isn't a multiplication: It's an attempt to call a function `p` with the argument `p-a`, which, as alexpdev pointed out in their comment, is an error because your `p` (of type `float`) isn't a function.  You need to explicitly write all the `*` operators.

```
ans = (p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)) ** (1/2)
```

Also, you got [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)  wrong: You've got `p = a + b + c`, but you need `(a + b + c) / 2`.